# Fetch distinct count of all columns in a single MySQL query

Tags: mysql, count, distinct, mysql-8.0

I am trying to fetch distinct count of all columns in a single query. Consider the below table.

```
COL1 | COL2 | COL3
A    | 5    | C
B    | 5    | C
C    | 5    | C
C    | 5    | C
D    | 7    | C
```

Expected result

```
DC_COL1 | DC_COL2 | DC_COL3     #DC - Distinct count
4       | 2       | 1
```

Though the above result can not be achieved (AFAIK) in a single query (single full table scan) using valid group by functions, what are the optimisations that could be done here?

Firing individual queries for each column might result in full table scan for each column. Though the entire table might have come to the buffer pool during the distinct count query for the first column but it will still be a performance issue on large tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done in a single table scan:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(DISTINCT COL1) DC_COL1,
  COUNT(DISTINCT COL2) DC_COL2,
  COUNT(DISTINCT COL3) DC_COL3
FROM tablename
```